# Add values to dict and increase list item's value by 1 if key is already in dict (python)

Tags: python, dictionary

Adding values to a dict and using a simple if statement to + 1 to the value if the key exists works fine with the following:

```
d = {word: (frequency, wordList[1]) for frequency, word in sorteddict}
for key, value in d.items():
    my_dict[key, value] = my_dict[key, value] + 1 if key in my_dict else value
```

I want to iterate over the dict "d" adding all the key value pairs to the dict "my_dict".

The problem I am having is that the dict's are key : list pairs and I only want to increase the value of list[0] if the key exists. For example:

```
d = {'smith': (1, 'jones')}

my_dict = {'smith': (2, 'jones')}
```

my_dict already contains the key 'smith' and so the logic would be:

```
+ 1 to list[0] else 1
```

Comment: What is the second value in the tuple?

Comment: these arent lists, these are tuples! you cant increment tuples!

Comment: the question is kind of hard to understand. did you mean something like this? `{x:(y[0]+1,y[1]) for x,y in d.items()}`

Comment: @Nullman: note that there are two dictionaries here: `d` and `my_dict`...

Comment: Yes thanks for pointing out the tuple/list error! I've corrected that now.

Comment: @Nullman `{x:(y[0]+1,y[1]) for x,y in d.items()}` is close to what I am trying to achive but as there are 2 dicts the +1 needs to occur as part of an if statement if the key already exists in my_dict

Comment: so like this? `{x:(y[0]+1 if my_dict.has_key(x) else 1,y[1]) for x,y in d.items()}`
the wording of the question is hard to understand, could you clarify it?

Comment: `{x: (y[0] + 1 if x in my_dict else 1, y[1]) for x, y in d.items()}` works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to clarify the question and answer:
the problem is that there are 2 dicts **d**, **my_dict**. each values is a tuple containing 2 items. what we want is to generate a new dict which has the keys and values of **d** but with the first item of the value tuple increased by 1 if the key exists in **my_dict** or set to 1 if it doesn't. we will achieve that like this:

```
{x: (y[0] + 1 if x in my_dict else 1, y[1]) for x, y in d.items()}
```